# Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart, split

I've got the following code which works well if there are tags present in the `widget.tagname` list.

```
List<String> split = widget.tagname?.split(',')??'';
```

However, if there are no tags in the list I get this error;

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `tagname` is `null`, then the compiler attempts to assign the value `''` to a `List<String>`, which is not possible. Replace `''` with `[]` and you should be fine.